# Proxy internet via FTP

Tags: networking

I have the following set up:

PC1 can connect to an FTP server only.

PC2 can connect to the same FTP server and internet.

i.e. the network looks like this:

PC1 <--> FTP <--> PC2 <--> internet

I would like to use the FTP server as an internet proxy for PC1 and just wondering if there's anything already in existence for it.

I have full control over PC1 and PC2, both are Linux boxes. I have absolutely no control over FTP server nor can I set up any other intermediate servers or services.

Basically i would want to have something similar to proxychains using FTP where my PC1 would be a client and PC2 an exit node.

Currently I have a simple push-pull script running, but its just not good enough.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to visit websites using the FTP server as a gateway.

Well, sadly, that's impossible. FTP and HTTP are totally different protocols, using different ports.

FTP is only for transferring files to and from remote locations. HTTP, on the other hand, is a protocol that sends data know as `headers` to a webserver, requesting various information, and is sent back return headers, files, cookies and so on. The two protocols will never meet.

What baffles me is why you have a machine that can only connect to an FTP server, but that's none of my business. I feel like I might be missing something in your question, so forgive me if this isn't an acceptable answer.

Comment: Yeah, the answer is acceptable considering... To put it another way, what i probably want is the ability to write an ip packet to the disk, read it and forward it on to its destination in a seemingly transparent way. This may of course not be very feasible as i would need to change the packet content every time (implement my own NAT).